# Redirect url using htaccess "/"

Tags: codeigniter, .htaccess

I have an issue on my website. The issue is that whenever I visit my website with this url: http://wowriters.com/assignment-writing-service
It is fine.

But whenever I visit my website with this url: http://wowriters.com/assignment-writing-service/
My website layout broken.

Kindly help me to handle it using "htaccess" or any other solution in "Codeigniter".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I am checking on localhost and my localhost url is this: http://localhost:81/php/wowriter/assignment-writing-service/

When I put your code in htaccess files, that is removing this "/php/wowriter".

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
```